# Taking screenshot with additional width or height iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Im currently taking screenshot of a UIScrollView as a part of app functionality. but i want to take the screenshot including additional height from the bottom. (UIScrollView+UIImageView)

[image]

This is how im taking UIScrollView screenshot now.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(ScrollView.bounds.size, true, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

        let offset = ScrollView.contentOffset

        CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -offset.x, -offset.y)

        ScrollView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0f);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage * snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return snapshotImage;
}
```

where your view parameter should be a content view.

Or you can take 2 shots, one of the ScrollView and another from the ImageView and merge in one:

```
- (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImage:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage {
    UIImage *image = nil;

    CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstImage.size.width, secondImage.size.width), MAX(firstImage.size.height, secondImage.size.height));
    if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize); 
    }
    [firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-firstImage.size.width)/2), 
                                        roundf((newImageSize.height-firstImage.size.height)/2))]; 
    [secondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-secondImage.size.width)/2), 
                                         roundf((newImageSize.height-secondImage.size.height)/2))]; 
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how to do the merge in one option in swift?

Comment: Yes, I can, but I don't have enough time right now, I'll be back later and translate it, and merge, ok?